# Run a linux/MacOS binary on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

I'm writing some code on windows and I want to use one third party library in my project. But the author of this library only provided binary files for MacOS and linux, no source code. I wonder, is it possible to use this library in my project? I mean, is there a method so that I can execute the binary in my C++ code.

It seems impossible, but I hope there is a miracle.

Comment: No - this is not possible - you will need to use Linux or Mac OS X.

Comment: For homework or school avoid using third party libraries which are not free and not blessed by your teacher.

Comment: It's for a research project, not for homework or school. The library I use is free for academic use. The author just didn't provide the source code for his own reason.@Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: Why not just install the free version of VMWare, Virtual PC, or HyperV, and just run Linux off of that?